# CSS круглая кнопка, при проверке на оптимизацию(для мобилок) через DevTools подсвечивает края?

Tags: css

Фото ореола прикладываю. Я как-то уже исправлял, но уже забыл ибо пауза была. Забыл отключить стиль по умолчанию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При просмотре через DevTools все блоки отображаются в виде прямоугольников.
Кнопка имеет круглый вид из-за стилей, но по прежнему является прямоугольником.

Comment: Так при нажатии в телефоне, это видно же....проверю на своем через локалку, но вроде так не должно быть.

Comment: @Алексей Для отключения синего эффекта при нажатии добавьте кнопке свойство -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; Но у этого свойства ещё совместимость не со всеми браузерами

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Как хорошо когда помнишь все что может быть полезным. Я уже копал в ту строну, но опта маловато)

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как принятый